# Pandas GroupBy for row number

Tags: python, pandas

I have enormous arrays of time-series data (~3GB, millions of rows) that I load into a dataframe through numpy memmap. I'd like to summarize them by getting descriptive statistics for each group of n elements (say 1000 per group). I really like the combination of group_by and describe but it seems like group_by is only useful for categorical data. If it wasn't a memmap I could add another column for time interval categories. Is there a way to get a GroupBy object that I can use describe on where the groups are by row index?

Comment: Why not recording your time series into an SQL database and use SQL instead? sqlite could help.

Comment: @Wli, I'm looking for simpler solutions to summarizing our data than rewriting the data-acquisition software to incorporate sql. I know I can write a loop to grab the data-frame in segments and summarize those, but I thought there might be a clever way to GroupBy using row number.

Comment: If I read again your question, I actually don't understand your last sentence. Perhaps this would help? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#window-and-resample-operations

Comment: Ok, sorry it's not clear. I'll add a description of something like what I have and what I'd like to have in the end based on it.